# Excel vlookup to get all occurrence cell details?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am doing automation on matching Data form row Data1 to Data 2,

I was done by looping statement but the problem is take much time, when number of row increase

For that reason i planed do by vlookup, In vlookup only return first occurrence cell but i need to find all match cell and highlighted matched row ,which i show in figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working with cells directly reduces the code performance. Try to set Data1 and Data2 to arrays and work with arrays.

Something like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    arr = .Range(.[A2], .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    arr2 = .Range(.[D2], .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value

    For i& = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j& = 1 To UBound(arr2)
            If arr(i, 1) = arr2(j) Then
                ...
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for this

```
Sub testvlookup()
    Dim lastrow, lastrowdata, incre, i, j As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowdata = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    incre = 6
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        For j = 2 To lastrowdata
            If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("D" & j).Value Then
                Range("D" & j, "G" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = incre
            End If
        Next j
        incre = incre + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: In this method, it take more time, for each form data1 to each in data 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point why it should be to slow for many rows, it would be good to have more informations about that.

I would do it like the others, takes ~1 sec with 100000 comparisons.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim b As Integer

i = 1

While i < 20000
Range("A1:A5").Copy Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i + 5, 4))
i = i + 5
Wend

MsgBox ("hi")
i = 1
While i < 7
   b = 3
While b < 20000
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(b, 4).Value Then
        Cells(b, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = i
    End If
b = b + 1
Wend
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```